# Batch File to change directory and run a command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to execute two cmd commands.This is my batch file:

```
set MW_HOME=D:\wls1211_dev
set JAVA_HOME=D:\jdk1.6.0_45
set JAVA_VENDOR=Oracle
set root=D:\wls1211_dev
set pathname=D:\WLSDomain
CD /D %root%
%MW_HOME%\wlserver\server\bin\setWLSEnv.cmd
CD /D %pathname%
startWebLogic.cmd
```

But after executing the setWLSEnv.cmd command its not moving to the next directory where it has to execute the startWebLogic.cmd .

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you directly invoke a batch file from inside a batch file, the execution is transfered to the called file and does not return.

You need to use `call %MW_HOME%\wlserver\server\bin\setWLSEnv.cmd` so when setWLSEnv.cmd ends, execution continues in your first batch file.